# Android : Device density is returned as zero from some devices

Tags: android

The device density return 0 from some devices. The following code is used to calculate device density:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
density = metrics.density;
```

This has resulted in some crashes in PlayStore. The users seem to be using: **Galaxy Y Plus ; Android version 4.0.3 - 4.0.4**. Also a device called **wing-k70** had problems. In one crash it was version **4.2**.

Please advice.

Answer (score 5):

There is not much you can do other than handle this gracefully.
If density is null or 0 check for it and use a default value in this case.

Comment: Even if there is a solution to find the density of these particular devices, it's likely this situation could reoccur with another model down the line.

Answer (score 4):

A good way to get the DPI is to generate a string.xml file for every density.

Create folders called values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi... and add a strings.xml in everyone, with a string called density with the value of the density (mdpi for strings.xml located in values-mdpi, etc)

then reading R.string.density will give you the correct density

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Comment: The only reason I haven't deleted this answer as a dupe is that this question is bountied and you cannot vote to close it as a duplicate. If this post is not a duplicate, make sure to tailor your answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following , it has some issues device earliar than API level 4

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```

Comment: sorry, Murtaza. this wouldn't work. As I mentioned in my question, it's not about devices earlier than Android version 4. It's happened in a device with version 4+

Comment: is it random or it is giving 0 every time on those devices?

Comment: P.S. there can be problem with rooted devices.